# For Orthogonal Unit Vectors, Prove that

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that for $n\geq 2$ there exist $n$ orthogonal unit vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $Au_1,\ldots,Au_n$ are also orthogonal.

As I recall this is a theorem but couldnt find its proof. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Are you sure this is a theorem? What if $A$ is not invertible? Say it maps everything to a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Then the collection $\left\lbrace Au_1, \cdots Au_n \right\rbrace$ will not be orthogonal.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh The zero vector is orthogonal to all vectors...

Comment: I am not sure. I saw this question in exercise. But I think I saw it somewhere as a theorem. Anyhow can you provide its proof please.

Comment: @5xum: Which is why I said that $A$ maps everything to a one-dimensional subspace. It can be the case that at least two of $Au_i$ are not mapped to the zero vector. But then, they are on the same "line" and hence not orthogonal to each other.

Comment: On second thought, though, in my case (if the statement is true), it would mean that there is some basis from which almost one vector is mapped to a non-zero vector.

Answer (score -1):

This seems just a direct consequence of the Singular Value Decomposition for any matrix. In fact, $A=UDV$, where $D$ is diagonal and $U,V$ are orthogonal. As a consequence, $AV^T = UD$, but the columns of both $V^T$ and $UD$ are orthogonal.

Comment: why the downvote?